# Webscraping csv files and merging into a single data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

I am currently trying to write an algorithm in python that automates a web scraping process. I want it to take a webpage address and merge everything that has the extension .csv into a single data frame on like columns. A picture of the format of the webpage is posted below along with a screenshot of my current code that takes in one csv file at a time and turns it into a data frame. Any help or guidance will be much appreciated, thanks!

[Webpage format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYEXX.jpg)

[Python code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOVdx.jpg)

Comment: Do not put links to your code in the question, put it in there.  This ensure that the question will be complete if ever the links go bad, or the images are removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to obtain all the links in the webpage.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import re

req = Request("http://website.com")
html_page = urlopen(req)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "lxml")

links = []
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    links.append(link.get('href'))

print(links)
```

Afterwards you can filter for the word 'csv' and iterate over the filtered list to get the csv data and append this in a pandas dataframe.